postgresql timestamptz conversion to localtime issue
i have two environments as below
   pre_prod  - ubuntu , postgres:12.18
   prod - ubuntu, postgres:12.18

I am facing very peculiar issue in both environments.
in pre_prod.
my timestamptz value is `

2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +0530

which has its timestamp absolute value with utc timezone.
In prod I do have same value…

2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +0530

But while rendering in Java, I see two different behavior's ..one is converting into IST, and another one is not converting into IST timezone..
         ----------------------------------------------------
            pre_prod                |      prod
         ----------------------------------------------------
          2024-03-27 07:00:00.000   |  2024-03-27 12:30:00.000        
         ----------------------------------------------------

as per below postgresql documentation

For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

i am seeing that, postgres has not converted my localtime stamp into utc, while storing it in database, 2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +0530 supposed to converted to utc and while reading it should convert back to IST timezone, which i have set as local time in postgres.

Asia/kolkata

so in preprod env, it is giving me absolute value as 2024-03-27 07:00:00.000  which is actually correct behavior's as per my requirement, so it has not converted to utc and while reading it is giving me correct value withou utc conversion, but as per above documentation ,it should convert to IST timezone, if it gets converted then it produce wrong timezone, which will be 2024-03-27 12:30:00.000.
so what is the correct behavior of posgres, seems like postgres is behaving differently, so i am considering to convert to timestamptz to timestamp due to this issue.
Edit:-
i have set timezone to 'Asia/kolkata' in ubuntu and same has been configured in my docker-compose, so both postgres and java service has  IST timezone.
my docker-compose.yml.
   java-service:
    image: prod:latest
    container_name: java-prod
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: /Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - prod_db
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: always
   prod_db:
    image: 'postgres:12.18-alpine'
    container_name: prod_db 
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw


root@srv529197:/opt/mas/prod# docker exec -it prod_db sh
/ # date
Thu May 23 16:55:38 IST 2024
/ #

  


Fetch the timestamptz into an OffsetDateTime in Java, and you should get the correct UTC offset from the database (and if not, you can convert yourself since you have an offset) (utc timezone would normally be understood as offset 0 from UTC; your +0530 can more accurately be termed an offset from UTC).

Make sure that the parameter timezone is set to Asia/Kolkata in the database session in your production environment. You can either start the Java virtual machine with that setting:
java -Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata ...

or set timezone in the PostgreSQL connection URI:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?options=-ctimezone=Asia/Kolkata


i have already set my timezone in docker-compose.yml, i have added details in edit section

That doesn't seem to help. Try my solution.

it worked after setting my java timezone.. to Asia/kolkatta.. wondering why my host time zone was not picked up my java..

seems like jvm is not picking my host timezone which it does always... in pre_prod i have version 17.0.10, in prod i have 17.0.11.. in later version the jvm is not picking up the host timezone, instead its defaulting to utc

Besides the good Answer by Albe, here are some more thoughts.
Always in UTC

For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC

Yes, Postgres always stores TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values in UTC, that is, with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
And be sure that your column is indeed defined as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE rather than as TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE. Always use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE when recording a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
Offset versus Zone
By the way, definitions:

OffsetMerely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC.
Time ZoneA time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

The SQL standard uses the words TIME ZONE but the authors really meant offset. The SQL standard authors did not fully understand date-time handling.
Moments must be defined with an offset or zone

2024-03-27 07:00:00.000   |  2024-03-27 12:30:00.000

Just to be clear, if you actually meant those examples to be 2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +00:00   |  2024-03-27 12:30:00.000 +05:30, then understand that those two strings would represent the very same moment. India time on that date used an offset +05:30, meaning five and a half hours ahead of UTC.  So half-past-noon in India time is the same moment as 7 AM in UTC. Same point on the timeline, two ways of viewing that one moment.

while storing it in database, 2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +0530

Is that example value a mistake on your part, using 07:00 where you really meant 12:30? Given the related example cited above, the 7 AM value would be UTC (offset of +00:00) while the 12:30 PM value would represent the same moment as seen with an offset of +05:30.
Be careful of such errors, as it really complicates understanding your Question. Please edit to fix.

my timestamptz value is 2024-03-27 07:00:00.000 +0530

Well, no, it is not. The value in your TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column is always in UTC (in Postgres, and some other databases). The stored value most certainly does not have an offset of +05:30. The stored value has an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, +00:00 (abbreviated as Z, pronounced “Zulu”).
Tools tell a lie
 Some database access tools, DBA tools, and middleware will lie to you. Such software may interject a default time zone during the retrieval process. Those tools will retrieve the stored UTC value, look up the current default time zone or offset, then apply that zone/offset to generate a new value. That new value arrives to you.
This unfortunate anti-feature creates the illusion of a zone/offset having been stored. Note that pgAdmin is one such tool with this anti-feature.
While the anti-feature is well-intentioned, I wish such tools would instead “tell the truth”, reporting the actual stored value, the UTC value.
Java
Fortunately, JDBC drivers do not have this anti-feature. When you retrieve an OffsetDateTime object from a Postgres TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column, you will always get an offset of zero. The resulting OffsetDateTime object reflects the truth of what was stored in the database.
OfssetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;

Storage:
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;  // If the passed `OffsetDateTime` object carries a non-zero offset, an adjustment to UTC is made before storage.

Focus on UTC

one is converting into IST, and another one is not converting into IST timezone..

I suggest you generally set your database session to use a default time zone of UTC.
Programmers and sysadmins should think in UTC while on the job, rather than in their own parochial time zone. Think of UTC as The One True Time, with all other zones being a mere variation. Data exchange, data storage, and logging should be done in UTC. Servers should be set to UTC. Keep a second clock on your desk/wall set to UTC.

i have set timezone to 'Asia/kolkata' in ubuntu

The host OS’ current default time zone should be irrelevant to your work and your app. Servers should be set to UTC. Your app should be written to explicitly specify any expected/desired time zone rather than rely on the whims/mistakes of the sysadmin.
If you want to see a moment through the wall-clock/calendar of a particular time zone, make that adjustment in your app. In Java code:
OfssetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zKolkata ) ;

Use DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime to generate localized text for display to user.
Tips
Fully expanded ISO 8601 format

+0530

I suggest you make a habit of using the fully expanded syntax for an offset. Per ISO 8601 standard, that format would be +05:00. While omitting the COLON character is technically allowed by the standard, I have found multiple protocols and libraries that expect it. Inclusion of the COLON also makes for easier reading.
And always include that leading zero on single-digit hours. Again, not required by ISO 8601, but many protocols & libraries expect it. And consistent inclusion makes reading easier.
Real time zone names

IST timezone

No, IST is not a time zone. Such 2-4 character pseudo-zones are used in localization, which should appear only in text being presented to the user, never in data storage or data exchange.
Such pseudo-zones are not standardized. They are not even unique! Did you mean Ireland Standard Time? Or India Standard Time?
Instead, use real time zone names in format of Continent/Region.
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  // India time.
ZoneId zDublin = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ) ;  // Ireland time.

tzdata updates
Politicians change the offset used in the time zone(s) under their jurisdiction surprisingly often.
When the rules change for a time zone of interest to your apps, be sure to update the tzdata file stored in all of these places:

Host operating system (OS)
Postgres database system
Java Virtual Machine (JVM) in your JDK

